# How to change background while changing visiblity?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, visibility

I set a section named "show" in my html file to invisible using `div id="show" style="display:none`, and tried to to change the visibility using `document.getElementById("show").style.display = "block"` in a JavaScript function.

Now my problem is, how can I change its background color while I change the section to visible? I tried to add in "background: yellow" in JavaScript after "block" and in CSS after "display", but neither of it worked. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: This is a very confusing question?  Can you put what you have in a fiddle or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make separate calls.

```
var node = document.getElementById("show");
node.style.display = "block";
node.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
```